# How to copy all my tumblr post ? Noob question

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hosting, tumblr

I'm using tumblr since a while with a friend to share musics from youtube, bandcamp, soucloud, etc.

We would like to make and host a page with all our posts linked in a big kind of spreadsheet :

A column for the name of the video (hyperlinked), a column for the website source.

I don't ask for a  turnkey solution... But I'm ready to follow the track you can show me.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Love
Greg

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) or build a **scraper** with solution like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Good day